# Get uuid of connection after adding it using nmcli

Tags: networking, openvpn, networkmanager, nmcli

I would like to add VPN connections to multiple machines and let them activate automatically when when using the default ethernet connection. However I need the UUID of the VPN connection I just added to configure the automatic connection.

What I have so far is importing the VPN connection using:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file some_dynamic_name.ovpn
Verbindung »some_dynamic_name« (0724d07e-4a31-488d-91e8-fd6031679dd6) erfolgreich hinzugefügt.
```

Where `some_dynamic_name` should be the `connection.id` and the uuid corresponds to the `connection.uuid`. Given this UUID I can now configure my target connection to automatically use the VPN using:

```
$ nmcli connection modify "Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1" connection.secondaries 0724d07e-4a31-488d-91e8-fd6031679dd6
```

Theoretically I could parse the output and pass it to the second command though I do not know if the output can be considered stable and I would like to add this to a script for unattended setup. Can I somehow specify the output format for the response? I know I can pass `--get-values connection.uuid` to the import command (directly after `nmcli`) though that does not change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know the name of the connection, you can use `-g` / `--get-values` to get its UUID after it has been created.

```
# nmcli --get-values connection.uuid c show "some_dynamic_name"
0724d07e-4a31-488d-91e8-fd6031679dd6
```

You could do it in one shot with shell substitution, something like this:

```
# nmcli c mod "Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1" connection.secondaries $(nmcli -g connection.uuid c show "some_dynamic_name")
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the file name always becomes the `connection.id`?

Comment: @Septatrix I just did a couple of tests. It appears NetworkManager is using the filename to set the connection name when importing an .ovpn file.